# Passing a model to an included JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Is there a way for me to pass my model to a JSP I include with a `<script/>` tag?

I'm trying to create some dynamic javascript, and I need the model to get access to an object which has a set of properties I need. I'm using liferay to automagically include the jsp, and I'm using a spring controller.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping
public String showForm( ModelMap model ){
model.addAttribute( "mykey", object );
return "myview";
}
```

Accessing `${mykey}` from `myview.jsp` works, but how do I get at the model from an included jsp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JSP which you include with a **`<script>`** tag? So that JSP represents a dynamically populated `text/javascript` response? No, that's certainly not possible. It get loaded by a completely *separate* HTTP request which won't contain the same attributes as the request which returned the parent HTML page. This is not to be confused with server-side includes using `<jsp:include>` which take place within the *same* HTTP request.

Apart from putting it in the session scope (which can have more caveats than you want), best what you could do is to just print the necessary data as a global JS variable.

```
<script>var foo = '${model.foo}';</script>
<script src="script.jsp"></script>
```

This way you can just access it the usual JS way inside the `script.jsp`.

I don't do Spring, but in theory you could just map some Spring controller on `script.jsp` as well so that it get its own model (which could just be the same as the one in parent JSP, whenever necessary).

Comment: Hmm. It really might make sense for this script to have its own model/controller. Then again, maybe I can get away with writing it in the original JSP.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the model is already in the request object. You should be able to access it from your included jsp. If that doesn't work, you will need to store it as a request attribute (you might be able to just reuse the one stored by Spring MVC)... then pass the request attribute name as a parameter to the included jsp:

```
<c:set var="myRequestModel" value="${model}" scope="request" />
<jsp:include ... >
   <jsp:param name="model" value="myRequestModel"/>
</jsp:include>
```

In your included jsp will use that name to access that model:-

```
${param.model.mykey}
```